# what if jmeter script has multiple graph listeners,In that case how can the results be stored in separate jtl files in non-gui mode?

Tags: jmeter

i have a script with disabled aggregate graph listener. I ran the test in non GUI mode.

jmeter.bat -t test.jmx -l result.jtl

After running the script,I opened the result file in aggregate graph listener and i was able to view the graph.
Now i need to add more graphical listeners to my script.How can I get separate result files for the listeners in non-GUI mode ( all listeners disabled in order to optimize the script).

I am able to open the result file in the aggregate graph listener . But when i tired opening same file in Response Time Graph, I get message -

**Unable to graph, not enough data**

Results.jtl file looks like this -->
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You do not need any listener in your test!! The below command is enough to create a result file for the test.

```
jmeter.bat -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
```

Once the result file is created, You just open them in any listener you want. the listener can you give the appropriate results - even the graph listeners.

You do NOT actually need any separate result file for each listener.

Comment: In addition to vins answer i can add that what is saved can be configured in the jmeter.properties file which is located in the bin folder

Comment: When i opened the file in aggregate listener, I was able to view the graph. How ever when i tried to open file in Response Time Graph , i get a pop with message "Unable to graph , not enough data". Attached the result file with query